# What does the multiple outputs in skip-gram mean?

Tags: machine-learning, word2vec

I've been trying to understand the process of skip-gram learning algorithm. There's this small detail that confuses me.

In the following graph(which is used in many articles and blogs to explain skip-gram), what does the multiple outputs mean? I mean, the input word is the same, the output matrix is the same. Then when you calculate the output vector, which I believe is the probability set of all words appearing near the input word, it should be the same all the time.

[skipgram model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JhYrZ.png)

Hope someone can help me with this~

Comment: I also found that many of the blogs and online resources explain the output layer awfully. The "multiple outputs" are simply different softmax units. The complication here is that we want to predict the probability of a given word at a context position so the use of softmax is more involved.

Answer (score 1):

[This article](https://mysaranshblog.wordpress.com/2016/11/10/skip-gram-architecture-of-word2vec-concisely-explained/) seems to explain it adequately — each "chunk" of the output represents the prediction of a word at one position in the context (the window of words before and after the input word in the text). The output is "really" a single vector, but the diagram is trying to make it clear that it corresponds to C instances of a word-vector where C is the size of the context.

Answer (score 0):

It's kind of a prone-to-misinterpretation diagram. Each of the three outputs in that diagram should be considered the results for a *different* input (context) word.

Feed it word *1*, and through the hidden layer, to the output layer, you'll get (size-of-vocabulary) V output values (at each node, assuming the easier-to-think-about negative-sampling mode) – the top results in the diagram. Feed it word *2*, and you'll get the middle results. Feed it word *3*, and you'll get the bottom results.

Comment: The answer below seems to be saying something different to yours.  When implementing the NN, do we have 1 or multiple softmax layers?  Do we have 1 or multiple weight matrices?

Comment: The specifics depend on your training mode – negative-sampling or hierarchical-softmax. In the common default negative-sampling mode – which also I personally find a lot easier to reason about – there's no true softmax layer. There are multiple weight matrixes: the input-words-to-hidden-layer 'projection' weights, and the hidden-layer-to-output-nodes output weights (named `syn1neg` in the original `word2vec.c` and `gensim`). But really, to understand, no prose explanation can match looking at the implementation code. So go there to really understand.