# Does the input of Skip gram model have multiple labels?

Tags: python, tensorflow, nlp, nltk, gensim

Assuming the source text is:

> The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog

And the window size is 2, like the following picture:

[image: window size is 2]

So we have a lots of training samples, and the format of training samples is (input, label).

For example:

> (the,quick), (the,brown), (quick,the), (quick,brown), (quick,fox).....

Does that mean the input (`quick`) has three output(`the`, `brown`, `fox`)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each of the 3 pairs – `(quick,the)`, `(quick,brown)`, `(quick,fox)` – essentially a separate training example.

Each pair is essentially presented to the shallow neural network independently, and the outputs of that network evaluated.

(That's either via the default negative-sampling sparse approach, where the output node for what you're calling the 'label' is checked, plus N other random laternatives, or via the alternative hierarcical-softmax, where just the nodes involved in the encoding of the 'label' word are checked. In either mode, only a tiny subset of the neural network's outputs are checked, for efficiency.)

To the extent those handful of checked outputs are not what are ideal for that one training example – a single pair – some corrective nudges are backpropagated. Then the next (*input*, *label*) is handled spearately.

It's only via the accumulated effect of all those contrasting examples, interleaved over many epochs, that the final network weights will reflect, in varying intensities that sometimes `quick` should activate `brown` more than other nodes, and other times `quick` should activate `fox` over other nodes.

So yes, in a sense, `quick` is associated in the skip-gram training micro-examples with 3 different desirable outputs, from just your one text. (In a good corpus, with many other subtly-varied usages of `quick`, it will also be associated, a varying number of times, with other potential outputs.)

Comment: `@gojomo` Thank you so much! It's much more thorough than I expect. Can I ask you another question? Here is the question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67574809/what-would-the-output-of-skip-gram-model-look-like

Comment: I gave some thoughts there, but mainly that's a question that's hard to evaluate meaningfully.